# Excel 2016 Option Explicit fails to detect undeclared variables

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

All sheets and all modules have Option explicit at the top.

*Require variable declaration* is ticked

I have just two sections of code, each in its own module.
But *Option Explicit* is being ignored.

As a test, I put in a new line of code

```
sausage = 3
```

and it compiled without error.

I've checked all the possible code sections in the workbook with the code below. It fails compilation in all of them except one. The entire code in that module is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectPath_Click()
s = 3
End Sub
```

Using Debug --> Compile VBA project produces no error, and the option to do it again is greyed out afterwards.

The code is as you can guess called when a button is clicked. I THINK the button is a Form control as opposed to an active-x, but I don't know how to query the button to find out what type it is.

There are no active add ins.

In the meantime, I have moved the sub from a Module to the sheet on which the button sits and hey, presto. Compilation fails.

So the question now is, how can this one part of the workbook ignore Option Explicit? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how to you compile? Debug-->Compile VBA Project?  Is the variable defined as global somewhere else?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided.  I get the `Compile error: Variable not Defined` with `sausage` highlighted.  Is `Option Explicit` a comment? Is `sausage` defined globally someplace?  Where is your code?  What is checked under `Error Trapping`?

Comment: I've tracked it down to  this. The problem is only in Module1, where this sub is called from a button click. Here is the entire code in that module?     Option Explicit

Sub SelectPath_Click()
s = 3
End Sub
It compiles with no error. All other codes sections throw up an error as they should with this same code. S is not defined anywhere (neither was sausage). To compile I use Debug --> Compile VBA project.

Comment: You can check if it is a `Form Control` or an `ActiveX Controle` when you go to the worksheet and right click it. `Form Control` should have a "Properties" or "View Code entry", `ActiveX Control` only has "Assign Macro". Since it fires the event `Button1_Click` it should be `FormControl`.

Comment: Thanks: In that case it's an Active X button. Still can't see why that should cause a module to ignore Option explicit, when the sheet code works as it should.

Answer (score 7):

Try this. It sounds stupid, but it actually repaired that condition for me on multiple occasions from Excel 2003 through (even this morning) on 2016. If it fails, you'll have only spent 30 seconds trying this admittedly bizarre workaround.

Position your cursor after the "t" in Explicit
Type a space (there's a bizarre technical reason for this; just trust me)
Hit enter
Hit left arrow key
Hit delete key

Now the compiler should do what you expected.

This is in case you did everything right, and you KNOW that Option Explicit is simply not working as it should, which is to give a compile error for undeclared variables.

Comment: I should have mentioned to FIRST click on the variable and go shift-F2, "just in case" a User 001 error actually slipped in, revealing that the variable indeed was publicly declared elsewhere :)

Comment: Regarding [your deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220282/472495), I wouldn't worry about the odd downvote. Voting is anonymous by design, and every time someone suggests downvotes must be justified, or that downvoting should not be allowed, it is rejected by the community.

Comment: I was going to suggest undeleting the other answer, but I see this question is a duplicate, so it is best for one to be closed as a dup of the other. If you wish to preserve the information in your deleted answer, you could copy it into this one.

Comment: tyvm for your respectful constructive advice, notably for acknowledging or at least implying that my solution had sufficient merit to suggest that I might paste it here.  BTW, admins then tagged that question, but not as a dupe, rather as *off topic.* Off topic, and not explicit and w/ sufficient problem demonstration (which can be rendered on 100.0% of posts). My takeaway is that terseness is inexplicit (ergo disallowed) and thorough elucidation is rejected as too wordy. You have to hit a sweet spot, and evidently I'm unqualified to do that. But your encouragement is taken in positive spirit.

Comment: It takes a while to learn the platform - there are a bunch of things that happen that are hard to explain without asking folks to read reams of [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) material and [Meta discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). It can be rewarding to be part of the community, but it takes a while to grok the norms and customs.

Comment: I agree with the closure on the other question. While this one was a dup of that one (in the sense that the other one was written first) there was no reproducible example and so readers are left to guess the nature of the problem. While this question feels like something that is hard to reproduce, there is a lot more detail to respond to (thus, if you have to choose between terseness and thorough elucidation, pick the latter).

Comment: Yes, your contribution has value - it is evident that it helped you, and it might help someone else. That is good in its own right. Not everyone will agree with those assertions and some folks will up/downvote based on their own assessments. Incidentally, the folks who closed the other question are not admins or mods - they are our fellow users. They have earned enough rep to "vote to close", which I think requires 3K.

Comment: Your solution actually fixed my problem so +1 to your answer.

Comment: Although this is an old post with old answers, it's the one SO found for me, and this simple technique hit the bug in the nuts (thanks FZ)! I think editing the code 10k times and fixing bugs all day can sometimes lead to this mysterious issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by moving the code from a Module, to the worksheet on which the button calling it was located.

Every other code area correctly failed to compile with duff code (Even the other module with a function in it.)

I had to re-assign the code to the button, but now it all works as it should.

But I have no idea why it should have failed before.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: This makes sense, the Button1_Click only works inside the class (yes a worksheet is handled like a class) it is actually used.

Comment: Also note my submitted solution. It sounds like you effectively achieved what I proposed, but unfortunately having to do a lot more work :(